# Sum of floor($\log(n)$) in base $x$ where $x$ goes from $2$ to $n$ and $x$ is not a pure power of some other integer is $n-1$.

Tags: number-theory

Interesting phenomena:

Let $f(x,n)$ be largest $k$ such that $x^k \leq n$. Then sum of $f(x,n)$ for $x = 2$ to $n$ will be $n-1$ where $x$ is not a pure power of some other number. That is $x \neq y^z$ where y, z are integers greater than 1.

> Let's take n=20. The numbers that are not a power of another integer 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, and 20.
>
> Note that $4=2^2, 8=2^3, 9=3^2, 16=2^4$. So they are excluded.
>
> Thus, $f(2, 20) = 4$ as $2^4 < 20$ but $2^5 > 20$
> Similarly, $f(3, 20) = 2, f(4, 20) = 2$. And for every other number in the list $f(x, 20) = 1$ as their squares will be greater than 20.
>
> Now adding all the numbers $f(2, 20) + f(3, 20) + f(4, 20) + others = 19 = 20 - 1$

This holds for all numbers.

Just noticed this while coding for a Project Euler problem.

Does anyone have some explanation why this happens ?

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow what you are saying.  Could you give any example, please?  In particular, wen you say $x\neq y^z$ do you mean $z$ to be an integer greater than $1$?

Comment: Hi @saulspatz I added an example and realized the solution as well.
When we are take f(2, 20) but excluding 4, 8, 16 we get f(2, 20) = 4 which counts exactly the number we have excluded. But since we're not taking 1 into consideration so the sum comes as n-1.